# How to make the button to the right, in a <ion-item>?

Tags: ionic3

like this:
the button not work,how to make button on the right side?

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-input placeholder="code" type="text"></ion-input>
      <button ion-button color="light">countdown</button>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input placeholder="code" type="text"></ion-input>
      <button ion-button color="light" item-end>countdown</button>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: Glad to see that you solved your question. Please consider adding some more information from Ionic Docs about what `item-end` is and how it works, so your answer could help other SO user facing the same issue :)

Comment: @sebaferreras ok, how to add ?